# python igraph gomory_hu minimal flow came out as the highest weighted edge

Tags: python, r, networking, graph, igraph

To give a bit of background - I am currently trying to create a particular network graph with a small number of nodes (reduced here to 5). I have a similarity matrix that I am using to create undirected weighted edges.

The headers for rows and columns can be 0-4, so for node 1 - node 2 the weight would be 0.6087.

```
[[1, 0.95238095238095233, 0.56521739130434778, 0.59090909090909094, 0.7142857142857143],
[0.95238095238095233, 1, 0.60869565217391308, 0.63636363636363635, 0.66666666666666663],
[0.56521739130434778, 0.60869565217391308, 1, 0.91304347826086951, 0.78260869565217395],
[0.59090909090909094, 0.63636363636363635, 0.91304347826086951, 1, 0.81818181818181823],
[0.7142857142857143, 0.66666666666666663, 0.78260869565217395, 0.81818181818181823, 1]]
```

I want to ultimately determine the maximum similarity value I can use as a minimum threshold for whether or not an edge is created between two nodes.  The purpose is to try to show modularity and subclusters, however I want to ensure that every node in the graph REMAINS connected through some series of edges.

When trying `gomory_hu` to calculate the `min_cut_tree` I got the following edges on the `gomory_hu` tree with the following flow values:

```
0-1,1-2,2-3,3-4

[2.8227931488801055, 2.864106907585168, 2.869565217391304, 2.958498023715415]
```

If I take the minimum flow back to the original graph that would imply that 0.95 is the cut value, which would eliminate all edges. Any insight into whether this approach is incorrect or if I am implementing it wrong would be highly appreciated.